# Why is my bonded pair of cats suddenly fighting?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, training

I have a bonded pair of cats: 1 male and 1 female. They are the same size and both were adopted from the shelter as kittens. Now, two years down the road, my male is suddenly attacking my female.

I have a few cats and one other female, but he never fights with anyone but his sister. Nothing has changed recently in the home and no medical issues. They have run of a 3-bed house.

I break up any fighting but it seems like it's getting more frequent.
Luckily my female is large and can handle her brother, but I'm starting to really get upset with my male as I can't see a reason for him to attack her in such a way. I'm adding more hides and perches as I can.

Any advice would help

Comment: Welcome at pets.SE! Which ones of them are neutered/spayed?

Comment: Can you describe the fighting a bit more? Does this appear to be a conflict getting resolved, fight that started as play and got out of hand, or potentially even mating behavior by the male (can occur even in neutered males, look for him jumping on the female from behind and trying to bite the neck)?

Comment: In any case, sudden changes in behavior warrant a visit to the vet, in this case with both your cats. The first thing you want to get off the table here is a medical issue as the root cause, e.g. a bad tooth causing pain and leading to aggression.

Comment: Has anything else in your life changed recently? New furniture, new schedule, anything with a new smell? Have either of the cats recently been to the vet or somewhere else where they could have picked up a new smell?